# What's the fastest way to integrate $\int \frac{ax±b}{cx±d} \, dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, linear-fractional-transformation

I know how to integrate $\int \frac{ax±b}{cx±d} \, dx$ where $a, b, c, d$ are real numbers, but for such an easy looking integral it takes me too much time, so how should I approach this problem to get the result faster?

Let's say we have this integral $\int \frac{2x-3}{5x-2} \, dx$. I would substitute $t=5x-2$, $dt=5dx$ and after that it's easy but takes too much time. I would be happy for any advice.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the point of the $\pm$ sign, unless you want to assume that $b$ and $d$ are nonnegative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, we can absorb the $\pm$ symbols into $b, d$, so we may as well take them both to be $+$.

In the generic case $a, c \neq 0$, se can pull off the leading coefficients andwrite $$\frac{a x + b}{c x + d} = \frac{a}{c} \cdot \frac{x + p}{x + q}$$ for $p = \frac{b}{a}, q = \frac{d}{c}$ and then rewrite $$\frac{x + p}{x + q} = \frac{x + q + (p - q)}{x + q} =  1 + (p - q) \cdot \frac{1}{x + q} .$$ Integrating, putting this all together, and making a slightly clever choice of constant that gives a cleaner expression gives:
$$\color{#df0000}{\boxed{\int \frac{a x + b}{c x + d} \,dx = \frac{a}{c} x - \frac{a d - b c}{c^2} \log |c x + d| +  C}}.$$

Of course, the cases with $a = 0$ and/or $c = 0$ immediately reduce to standard elementary integrals.

Comment: You beat me to it +1

Comment: Thank you. Can you please also explain how you got log|cx+d|, shouldn't there be log|x-q|?

Comment: Sure: Like you say, integrating $\frac{1}{x + q}$ (I corrected a sign error in the answer just now, by the way) gives $\log|x + q| + D = \log |x + \frac{d}{c}| + D$, giving for the original integral the antiderivative $\frac{a}{c} x - \frac{ad - bc}{c^2} \log\left|x + \frac{d}{c}\right| + D$. Now, $\log\left|x+\frac{d}{c}\right| + \log|c| = \log\left|cx+d\right|$, so by pulling an appropriate multiple of $\log|c|$ out of the constant $D$ (leaving a new constant, say, $C$), we can rearrange and produce the antiderivative in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**:

Canonical form of a homographic function:
$$\frac{2x-3}{5x-2}=\frac{\frac25(5x-2)-\frac{11}5}{5x-2}=\frac 25-\frac{11}5\frac{1}{5x-2}=\frac 25-\frac{11}{25}\frac{1}{x-\frac25}$$

Comment: Why do you think that someone asking a question about a simple integration would know what a homographic function is?

Comment: @clathratus: because I learnt the name in high school (it was in, the curriculum).

Comment: you must've gone to a really good high school. (I didn't mean to sound aggressive BTW)

Comment: Well, here in France, all high schools have the same curriculum.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\frac{ax\pm b}{cx\pm d}dx=\int\frac{\frac ac x\pm \frac bc}{x\pm \frac dc}dx=\int\frac{\frac ac(x\pm \frac dc)\mp\frac{ad}{c^2}\pm \frac bc}{x\pm \frac dc}dx=\frac ac x+\left(\mp\frac{ad}{c^2}\pm \frac bc\right)\int\frac 1{x\pm \frac dc}dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Any rational function, of which this is a particularly simple example,  can be integrated using the method of [partial fractions](https://www.math24.net/integration-rational-functions/) .